# How do I cover up half of a multiplication table?

Tags: java, if-statement, multi-table

So we need to write a program where you input a number and the program generates a multiplication table that looks like a ramp going to the right, or a right triangle.

[image]

I have been able to generate a square table, but now I need to use an if statement to place a space instead of numbers to create the shape. I'm having a tough time figuring out what condition needs to be true to put a space instead of the number

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maxlength;
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive max number: ");
        maxlength = input.nextInt();
        
        double multi;
        
        for (int row = 0; row <= maxlength; row++) {
            for (int  count = 0; count <= maxlength; count++) {
                multi = count * row;
                
                System.out.printf("%3.0f ", multi);
            }
        System.out.println(""); 
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you write an example output?

Comment: It would also help to give an example of the desired output vs the current example output.

Comment: i added sample output picture

Comment: The only condition I see is if x + y >= max print number, otherwise print spaces.